# Running same job in Parallel using Jenkins and build flow

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-build-flow

I am trying to run the same automated job (Deriv_Client_Add) in parallel with different parameters:

```
parallel(
  {build("GUI/Deriv_Client_Add", Branch:params.Branch, Config:params.Conf)}
)
```

If I run this job multiple times with a different branch and config it queues them up.  Is there a way to run the same job multiple times in parallel?

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try below Plugin which suit your requirement
```

[CheckThis](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin)

Comment: @Paul Morriss please accept my answer if you  found this helpful , so that others can use the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

First check your number of Executor.

If you have 2 executors then you can run 2 jobs in parallel

If you want to run more job in parallel then increase executor number (from node configuration)

Try [Build Flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin)

example:

```
 parallel(
 {build("job1")},
 {build("job2")}
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your job -> configuration and check the Boolean: **`Do not allow concurrent builds`**